# Do the "get" operation consume additional memory

Tags: node.js, memory-management, redis

I have a key in Redis, let's call it 'key', so it consumes an amount of memory.
Then I have a Nodejs application with Redis driver, I get that 'key' by simple API

```
var data = await redis.get('key')
```

So my question is, do the 'data' variable create new memory consumption other than use the original memory address of 'key' that is currently used by Redis

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is new and also different memory.

Redis is running in a different process and your node application is a different process. Two processes have different memory spaces. They are not shared. So when you grab the key - somewhere in your node js memory now that data also exists

That's why you are using a client that goes over the network over tcp to grab the data - the memory is not shared